# Cómo incrementar el número dentro de una cadena

Tags: javascript, regex

El problema es el siguiente: tengo que devolver la parte numeral del string sumado +1 , lo que me devuelve también tiene que ser string. Por ejemplo:

```
incrementString("foobar000")   // "foobar001"  
incrementString("foo")         // "foo1"  
incrementString("foobar001")   // "foobar002"  
incrementString("foobar99")    // "foobar100"  
incrementString("foobar099")   // "foobar100"  
incrementString("")            // '1'  
incrementString("foobar00999") // "foobar01000"  
incrementString("009")         // '010'
```

Trate de resolverlo, pero no pude. Ésta es una sección de mi código:

```js
var strng = "foobar000"; // esto podría ser strng ='foobar001'
var numero = strng.slice(-1);      
var convertido2 = parseInt(numero) +1;
console.log(strng.replace(numero,convertido2));
```

Comment: Cuando usas `strng.indexOf('0')` te devuelve 6 porque esa es la posición del primer cero en la cadena. En tu código no muestras como lo cambias, de modo que no puedo indicarte más al respecto. Has pensado que vas a hacer cuando la suma en el extremo llegue a 9?

Comment: @Frnk Debes aclarar cuales son tus intenciones. Lo que entiendo es que quieres sumarle 1 al ultimo dígito. Pero no se si estoy en lo correcto

Comment: @NeryOrtez asi es , es sumarle a la parte numeral del string

Comment: @Frnk Bien... Entonces la pregunta de quevedo es válida: Que hacer cuando esa suma llegue o supere a 9 ? El penultimo digito se afecta? Se reinicia a cero?

Comment: @NeryOrtez era una seccion de mi codigo para resolver un problema , ahora lo edito ,  ayer estaba tratando de resolverlo , pero no pude.

Comment: Complicado problema tienes, revisarlo debo. Si otros quieren resolverlo también, me enojo yo no.

Comment: @NeryOrtez jajaja si , me la pase ayer intentando , llege hasta que 1 condicion me fallaba , luego me rendi . Si alguien lo resuelve , se lo agradeceria .

Comment: @Frnk la solución de Álvaro Montoro es más simple y elegante. Te aconsejo que marques esa como respuesta correcta porque ayudaría más a un usuario que llegase con la misma duda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He hecho una pequeña función que hace lo que quieres. La idea es quedarse con los dígitos que haya al final de la cadena, eliminarlos de la cadena inicial, incrementar el valor en 1, agregarles 0 delante, y volver a añadirlos a la cadena.

Aquí puedes ver el código comentado y corriendo:

```js
function incrementString(cadena) {
  // nos quedamos con el numero del final o "" si ninguno
  var er = /(\d)*$/;
  var numeros = er.exec(cadena)[0];
  
  // guardamos el numero de digitos
  var longitud = numeros.length;
  
  // incrementamos el numero en 1
  var incremento = parseInt(numeros || 0)+1;
  
  // al incremento le agregamos 0s delanteros
  var strIncremento = incremento.toString().padStart(longitud, "0");
  
  // concatenamos la nueva cadena
  var nuevaCadena = cadena.substring(0, cadena.length - longitud) + strIncremento;
  
  // y la devolvemos
  return nuevaCadena;
}


console.log(incrementString("foobar000"));   // "foobar001"  
console.log(incrementString("foo"));         // "foo1"  
console.log(incrementString("foobar001"));   // "foobar002"  
console.log(incrementString("foobar99"));    // "foobar100"  
console.log(incrementString("foobar099"));   // "foobar100"  
console.log(incrementString(""));            // '1'  
console.log(incrementString("foobar00999")); // "foobar01000"  
console.log(incrementString("009"));         // '010'
```

Comment: En realidad me gusta más tu solución. Es más simple y de paso usa el método nativo `padStart` que no tenía idea que existía. (Ahora veo que es ECMAScript 2017. Salvo en explorer, debiera tener soporte universal)

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que resolver dos problemas.

**Primero**, dado el string obtener la parte numérica y la no numérica. Esto lo puedes hacer con una expresión regular:

```
var captura = /([^\d]*)(\d*)$/.exec(strgn);
```

Esto significa: "captura todas las ocurrencias de un caracter no numérico en el grupo 1, y todas las ocurrencias de un caracter numérico **previas al final del string** en el grupo2".

Esto significa que `foobar000` devuelve `foobar` en el grupo1 y `000` en el grupo 2.

También significa que `123foobar000` retorna idéntico resultado, dado que los primeros tres números no están al final del string.

También significa que dado un string sólo numérico `12345` el grupo1 sea `""` y que dado un string sin números, el grupo2 sea `""` (strings vacíos).

El uso del * en la expresión regular significa que capturo cero o más ocurrencias del patrón.

Ambos grupos de captura son de tipo texto.

**Tu segundo problema** es que para sumar 1, debes hacer la lógica:

1. Si el elemento es "", considerarlo 0 (de lo contrario, parseInt dirá `NaN`
2. Convertir el elemento a número
3. Sumarle 1
4. asegurarte de que conserve al menos el largo inicial (los ceros delante del dígito significativo)
5. devolver la concatenación del grupo1 con el número modificado

Para el punto 4, declaré una función auxiliar que le pone ceros al principio hasta cumplir con un largo mínimo.

```js
incrementString("foobar000") //"foobar001"
incrementString("foo") //"foo1"
incrementString("foobar001") // "foobar002"
incrementString("foobar99") // "foobar100"
incrementString("foobar099") //"foobar100"
incrementString("") // '1'
incrementString("foobar00999") //"foobar01000"
incrementString("009") //'010'
incrementString("123aaa009") //'010'

function pad(num, largo) {
  var numero_str = num + "";
  while (numero_str.length < largo) {
    numero_str = "0" + numero_str;
  }
  return numero_str;
}

function incrementString(strgn) {
  var captura = /([^\d]*)(\d*)$/.exec(strgn);
  var grupo1 = captura[1];
  var grupo2 = captura[2]; // el número en forma de texto
  var largo_del_numero = grupo2.length;
  var convertido2 = parseInt(grupo2 || 0, 10) + 1;
  var numero_con_ceros = pad(convertido2, largo_del_numero);
  var subcadena=strgn.substring(0,strgn.length - largo_del_numero);
  var concatenacion = grupo1 + numero_con_ceros;
  
  console.log('"'+strgn+'"','devuelve','"'+concatenacion+'"');
  return concatenacion;
}
```

Esta es una manera de resolverlo. Otra manera, por ejemplo si quisieran que `123foobar0010` devolviese `123foobar0011` sería ignorar el primer grupo y en campo usar un substring del texto original quitando los N últimos dígitos, siendo N el largo del número.

Si te fijas, definí una variable `subcadena` que es lo que te puse arriba. Si ese es el resultado deseado, entonces donde dice:

```
var subcadena=strgn.substring(0, strgn.length - largo_del_numero);
var concatenacion = grupo1 + numero_con_ceros;
```

Debiera decir

```
var subcadena=strgn.substring(0, strgn.length - largo_del_numero);
var concatenacion = subcadena + numero_con_ceros;
```

Comment: los paréntesis en la expresión regular divide la búsqueda en 2 string resultados ?

Comment: Los paréntesis implican grupos de captura. En este caso capturo dos grupos. Para lo que importa, podrías capturar sólo el grupo numérico y usar el método de la subcadena al final. Ojo, el resultado de `exec` retorna en primer lugar toda la cadena que hizo match, los grupos vienen en los índices 1 en adelante. Por ejemplo, si sólo quisieras capturar el grupo numérico, podrías usar algo como `/[^\d]*(\d*)$/.exec('lalalala100')`. El primer elemento del resultado es `lalalala100` porque toda la cadena calzó con el regex

Comment: Depende del resultado deseado. Por eso en el último párrafo puse la sustitución que debiera hacerse en caso de que el resultado esperado sea el segundo